# Display Empty Fields Above and Below Filed

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

Im trying to render a report with fields having empty fields in the data and they render like:

```
Precaution1
Precaution2


Precatuion
```

The schema relates to orders, and when I pull only "Precaution1" and "Precaution2" its rendering staggered for the same Person its Attached to. I created separate sub reports for both. But when rendered they render like:

```
Bob: Precation1
                Precation2
Bill:           Precaution2
     Precaution1
Jill:Precaution1 Precaution
```

Is this a formatting issue? Or is it possible that because these tables have dates attached to them they are being staggered?